# MYSQL query duplicating the rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having the problem that the query I'm passing through a function is duplicating me the rows. Before, instead of the statement->execute(array()), I had PARAM_STR working for each value. However, it started to give me problems. This is the code that is duplicating me the rows.

```
static public function mdlIngresarUsuario($datos){
    $statement = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (id, nombre, usuario, password, rol, estado) VALUES (null, :nombre, :usuario, :password, :rol, :estado)");
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
        ':usuario' => $datos['usuario'],
        ':password' => $datos['password'],
        ':rol' => $datos['rol'],
        ':estado' => 0
    ));
    if ($statement->execute()) {
      return "ok";
    } else {
      return "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error message from the query? if so, please provide it in your question.

Comment: No. Everything is running perfectly, with the exception that each row inserted is being duplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're executing the statement twice:

```
$statement->execute(array(
':nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
':usuario' => $datos['usuario'],
':password' => $datos['password'],
':rol' => $datos['rol'],
':estado' => 0
));
```

and then in the condition of the if statement:

```
if ($statement->execute()) {
  return "ok";
}
```

Just log the return of the first "execute", and use that as the condition:

```
$success = $statement->execute(array(
':nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
':usuario' => $datos['usuario'],
':password' => $datos['password'],
':rol' => $datos['rol'],
':estado' => 0
));
if( $success ) { return "ok"; }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you call `$statement->execute` twice, once where you 'create' it and once in the if statement. You should assign the value of the first execute to a variable and use that variable in the if statement, like:

```
public static function mdlIngresarUsuario($datos)
{
    $statement = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (id, nombre, usuario, password, rol, estado) VALUES (null, :nombre, :usuario, :password, :rol, :estado)");
    $result = $statement->execute(array(
        ':nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
        ':usuario' => $datos['usuario'],
        ':password' => $datos['password'],
        ':rol' => $datos['rol'],
        ':estado' => 0
    ));
    if ($result) {
        return "ok";
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
}
```